# I am moving my windows partition to a SSD, how can I keep my already esxisting dual boot that exists on my HDD with windows and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Basically I currently have one HDD where on different partitions I have windows and Ubuntu installed and my dual boot is working perfectly.

But I just bought a SSD and I am planning to move my windows and associated partition to the SSD leaving Ubuntu on HDD.

I am just wondering, will copying be enough or do I need to do some extra steps to make it work.

Comment: You should really reinstall both operating systems onto the SSD. Windows and Linux do use special options when installed onto a SSD. If you just copy your old OS from HDD to SSD, you might end with a system crash or your SSD might not run optimal, your SSD might be worn out faster.

Answer (score 0):

Some extra steps will be needed to make it work. You cannot just copy an installation to another disk. You typically will need to reinstall, unless you have deep technical skills to adopt an existing installation to the changed hardware configuration.

While you are at the point to reorganize your system, I strongly recommend you also move Ubuntu to the SSD. Having your operating system on an SSD makes for an enormous boost in performance. If you have sufficient space, also use the SSD for your current work, and use the HDD for data storage, i.e., archives, music, etc.